# Mysql: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have three tables

```
 DGRS TABLE                     SPVS TABLE         LOCS TABLE
------------------             ------------       ---------------------
dgr_date                       sid (PK)           mloc (PK)
mc_loc (fk:locs:mloc)          sname              spid (fk:spvs:sid)
ws                             state
daily_gen
```

Below mysql query is taking 7 minutes (on mysql terminal) to return the result and hanged in phpmyadmin:

```
select s.sname, sum(d.daily_gen) 
from spvs as s, dgrs as d, locs as l
where s.sid=l.spid and l.mloc=d.mc_loc and d.dgr_date='2014-11-30'
group by s.sname;
```

Explain of above query result:

```
id  select_type table   type   possible_keys    key     key_len ref        rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE      s       ALL    PRIMARY          NULL    NULL    NULL        20   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      l       ref    PRIMARY,fk_spid  fk_spid 4       oms.s.sid   9    Using index
1   SIMPLE      d       ref    fk_mcloc fk_mcloc        102     oms.l.mloc  485  Using where
```

How to optimize the query? DGRS table has .5 million records.

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 285 -error is displaying in phpmyadmin.

Comment: comma joins are sooo last year

Comment: Consider providing an index on (mc_loc,dgr_date) - instead of the one you (presumably) already have on dgrs.mc_loc alone.

Comment: Great! Mr. Strawberry. It solved the issue. I added the Index on dgr_date and it's all done. Thanks.